# XML Serializes Properly but Cannot Deserialize Array Objects

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

I have a project where I need to serialize XML.  My XSD is targeted by both a Java Library and a C# .NET 4.0 library.  My C# library seems to be having problems de-serializing specific XML.

This is the XML in question.

```
<FbiXml>
    <Ticket>
        <UserID>1</UserID>
        <Key>qqym2OmtNjiUOBDbfr2tXg==</Key>
    </Ticket>
    <FbiMsgsRs statusCode="1000">
        <SaveSORs statusCode="1000">
            <SalesOrder>
                <ID>517</ID>
                <Note/>
                <TotalPrice>0.07</TotalPrice>
                <TotalTax>0</TotalTax>
                <ItemTotal>0</ItemTotal>
                <Salesman/>
                <Number>629</Number>
                <Status>20</Status>
                <Carrier>Delivery</Carrier>
                <FirstShipDate>2013-12-20T08:43:46</FirstShipDate>
                <CreatedDate>2013-12-20T08:43:46</CreatedDate>
                <IssuedDate>2013-12-20T08:43:46</IssuedDate>
                <TaxRateName>None</TaxRateName>
                <ShippingTerms>Prepaid &amp; Billed</ShippingTerms>
                <PaymentTerms>COD</PaymentTerms>
                <CustomerContact/>
                <CustomerName>Stackoverflow</CustomerName>
                <CustomerID>19</CustomerID>
                <FOB>Origin</FOB>
                <QuickBooksClassName>None</QuickBooksClassName>
                <LocationGroup>Main</LocationGroup>
                <PoNum/>
                <PriceIsHomeCurrency>true</PriceIsHomeCurrency>
                <BillTo/>
                <Ship/>
                <Cost>0</Cost>
                <Items>
                    <SalesOrderItem>
                        <ID>3725</ID>
                        <ProductNumber/>
                        <SOID>-1</SOID>
                        <Description>Adjustment Amount</Description>
                        <Taxable>false</Taxable>
                        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                        <ProductPrice>0.07</ProductPrice>
                        <TotalPrice>0.07</TotalPrice>
                        <UOMCode>ea</UOMCode>
                        <ItemType>11</ItemType>
                        <Status>-1</Status>
                        <Note/>
                        <QuickBooksClassName/>
                        <NewItemFlag>true</NewItemFlag>
                        <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
                        <AdjustmentAmount>0</AdjustmentAmount>
                        <AdjustPercentage>0</AdjustPercentage>
                        <QtyFulfilled>0</QtyFulfilled>
                        <QtyPicked>0</QtyPicked>
                        <TotalCost>0</TotalCost>
                        <TaxID>1</TaxID>
                        <TaxRate>0.1</TaxRate>
                        <TaxCode>None</TaxCode>
                    </SalesOrderItem>
                </Items>
            </SalesOrder>
        </SaveSORs>
    </FbiMsgsRs>
</FbiXml>
```

I am testing my C# library with this code.

```
using FishbowlSDK;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace TestFishbowlLibrary
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            testSODeserialize();
        }

        public static void testSODeserialize()
        {
            String XML = Resource1.SOXMLTEST001;
            FbiXml fbixml = new FbiXml();
            System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer xml = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(fbixml.GetType());
            xml.UnknownAttribute += new XmlAttributeEventHandler(Serializer_UnknownAttribute);
            xml.UnknownElement += new XmlElementEventHandler(Serializer_UnknownElement);
            String rs = XML;
            rs = rs.Replace(@"<FbiXml>", @"<FbiXml xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns=""FishbowlSDK"">");
            StringReader sr = new StringReader(rs);
            XmlTextReader xtr = new XmlTextReader(sr);
            FbiXml Response = (FbiXml)xml.Deserialize(xtr);
            SaveSORsType loadsors = (SaveSORsType)Response.FbiMsgsRs.Items[0];
            SalesOrder so = loadsors.SalesOrder;
            if (so.Items.Count == 0)
            {
                throw new Exception("This XML has Sales Order Items, but it deserialized none!");
            }            
        }

        private static void Serializer_UnknownAttribute(object sender, XmlAttributeEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unknown Attribute");
            Console.WriteLine("\t" + e.Attr.Name + " " + e.Attr.InnerXml);
            Console.WriteLine("\t LineNumber: " + e.LineNumber);
            Console.WriteLine("\t LinePosition: " + e.LinePosition);
        }

        private static void Serializer_UnknownElement(object sender, XmlElementEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unknown Element");
            Console.WriteLine("\t" + e.Element.Name + " " + e.Element.InnerXml);
            Console.WriteLine("\t LineNumber: " + e.LineNumber);
            Console.WriteLine("\t LinePosition: " + e.LinePosition);
        }


    }
}
```

This is a snippet of the full XSD.  Just the Sales Order Object.

```
<xs:element name="SalesOrder">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="Note"   type="xs:string"   minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="TotalPrice"   type="xs:string"   minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="TotalTax"   type="xs:string"   minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="ItemTotal"   type="xs:string"   minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="Salesman"   type="xs:string"   minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="Number"   type="xs:string"   minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="Status"   type="xs:integer"   minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="Carrier"   type="xs:string"   minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="FirstShipDate"   type="xs:dateTime"   minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="CreatedDate"   type="xs:dateTime"   minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="IssuedDate"   type="xs:dateTime"   minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="TaxRateName"   type="xs:string"   minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="ShippingTerms"   type="xs:string"   minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="PaymentTerms"   type="xs:string"   minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="CustomerContact"   type="xs:string"   minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="CustomerName"   type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="CustomerID"   type="xs:integer" />
            <xs:element name="FOB"   type="xs:string"   minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="QuickBooksClassName"   type="xs:string"   minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="LocationGroup"   type="xs:string"   minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="PoNum"   type="xs:string"   minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="BillTo"   type="tns:BillType"   minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="Ship"   type="tns:ShipType"   minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="IssueFlag"   type="xs:boolean"   default="false" />
            <xs:element name="VendorPO"   type="xs:string"   minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="CustomerPO"   type="xs:string"   minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="TotalIncludesTax"   type="xs:boolean"   minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="TypeID"   type="xs:integer"   minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="URL"   type="xs:string"   minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="Cost"   type="xs:double"   minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="DateLastModified"   type="xs:dateTime"   minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="SalesmanInitials"   type="xs:string"   minOccurs="1" />
            <xs:element ref="tns:CustomFields"   minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element ref="tns:Memos"   minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element ref="tns:Items"   minOccurs="0" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

This is the object code in the C# Library.  It was generated with xsd2code.

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(Order = 35)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("SalesOrderItem", IsNullable = false)]
public List<SalesOrderItem> Items
{
    get
    {
        return this.itemsField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.itemsField = value;
    }
}
```

This is what my test code outputs.

```
Unknown Element
    PriceIsHomeCurrency true
     LineNumber: 25
     LinePosition: 52
Unknown Element
    BillTo 
     LineNumber: 26
     LinePosition: 14
Unknown Element
    Ship 
     LineNumber: 27
     LinePosition: 12
Unknown Element
    Cost 0
     LineNumber: 28
     LinePosition: 19
Unknown Element
    Items 
      <SalesOrderItem xmlns="FishbowlSDK">
        <ID>3725</ID>
        <ProductNumber />
        <SOID>-1</SOID>
        <Description>Adjustment Amount</Description>
        <Taxable>false</Taxable>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        <ProductPrice>0.07</ProductPrice>
        <TotalPrice>0.07</TotalPrice>
        <UOMCode>ea</UOMCode>
        <ItemType>11</ItemType>
        <Status>-1</Status>
        <Note />
        <QuickBooksClassName />
        <NewItemFlag>true</NewItemFlag>
        <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
        <AdjustmentAmount>0</AdjustmentAmount>
        <AdjustPercentage>0</AdjustPercentage>
        <QtyFulfilled>0</QtyFulfilled>
        <QtyPicked>0</QtyPicked>
        <TotalCost>0</TotalCost>
        <TaxID>1</TaxID>
        <TaxRate>0.1</TaxRate>
        <TaxCode>None</TaxCode>
      </SalesOrderItem>

     LineNumber: 55
     LinePosition: 13
```

So my c# knows that there is an known element. But why?  Since I can generate a Sales Order object programmatically, and the XML is serialized properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.  It was the Unknown Element of "PriceIsHomeCurrency" because of that the order of the object was now different than what the deserializer expected, and therefore thought that the Items element was unknown.  Fixing this unknown element resolved the serialization issue.